# How to save and load an array list of objects?

Tags: java, arraylist, save, load

I have a class Employees that has methods add, delete, display and search employees in an array list. Now I'm trying to create a file handler to save and read this data but for some reason it isn't working and it isn't creating a file or reading it. Can anyone find a problem with my code please?

Comment: You have swallowed all the exceptions. Use `ex.printStackTrace()` to display the exception information which will show you the problem.

Comment: Using your code, I am able to add 1000 employees to a list, write to a "employee.obf" of size 6024 and read it back into a list, and finally assert the size. Could it be a problem with write-access?

Comment: @Jeppe If it is a problem with write-access how do I fix it?

Comment: @m.18 First try Karol's suggestion of printing the stacktrace of the exception in your writeDate-function - it should tell you exactly what the problem is.

Comment: @Jeppe ok but how should I run the function? What parameter do I pass to it?

Comment: @m.18 Are you referring to writeDate or printStackTrace?

Comment: @Jeppe writeDate because printStackTrace is in writeDate

Comment: @m.18 I have added an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution tests EmployeeFileHandler and shows the error if e.g the directory is not writable. Run with `javac EmployeeFileHandler.java; java -ea EmployeeFileHandler` to have it crash if assertion fails. Ensure the Person class is also Serializable.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class EmployeeFileHandler implements Serializable {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Employees> employees = new ArrayList<Employees>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
            employees.add(new Employees("Name" + i, "Surname" + i, "" + i, 12345678));
        }        
        writeDate(employees);

        ArrayList<Employees> employees2 = new ArrayList<Employees>();
        readData(employees2);

        assert employees.size() == employees2.size();
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
            Employees e = employees2.get(i);
            assert e.Name.equals("Name" + i);
            assert e.Surname.equals("Surname" + i);
            assert e.ID.equals("" + i);
            assert e.MobNo == 12345678;
        }        
    }

    public static void readData(ArrayList<Employees> listIn) {

        boolean endOfFile = false;
        Employees temp;

        try {

            FileInputStream employeesFile = new FileInputStream("employee.obf");
            ObjectInputStream employeesStream = new ObjectInputStream(employeesFile);
            temp = (Employees) employeesStream.readObject();

            while (endOfFile != true) {
                try {
                    listIn.add(temp);
                    temp = (Employees) employeesStream.readObject();
                } catch (EOFException e) {
                    endOfFile = true;
                }
            }
            employeesStream.close();
        }

        catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Employee file was not found");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Employee file could not be read");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Employee class was not found");
        }
    }

    public static void writeDate(ArrayList<Employees> employee) {

        try {
            FileOutputStream EmployeesFile = new FileOutputStream("employee.obf");
            ObjectOutputStream EmployeesStream = new ObjectOutputStream(EmployeesFile);

            for (Employees employees : employee) {
                EmployeesStream.writeObject(employees);
            }
            EmployeesStream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // System.out.println("Error occurred while saving");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: For some reason I can't get this to work cause I can't figure out what parameter to pass.

Comment: @m.18 What do you mean by parameters? If you run the code as I have written, it will build a mock-collection of Employees, write them to file and read them back up into another collection. :-)

Comment: oh ok so that worked and the employee.obf file was created.

Comment: @m.18 Awesome. So the problem must be somewhere else. Can you alter you question with more information?

Comment: I added how an employee is added from the main class but I doubt it makes a difference. What other information should I send?

Comment: @m.18 Oh, I didn't actually have much of a look on Employees. But I think you can help yourself a lot by refactoring your class a bit. Your "Employees" class, is really just a single Employee (so call it that). Instead of having a static ArrayList inside the Employees class - move it out to your "main class" and add it there directly. Its a bit counter-intuitive that you use the same class to store employees, as the class you use for a single employee (even though it is static). Can you show the code where you call "EmployeeFileHandler.writeDate"?

Comment: @m.18 Actually, the problem may in fact be your static field, as I believe static fields are ignored during serialization of an object.

Comment: Where should the EmployeeFileHandler.writeDate be called? Because I'm not calling it anywhere. This is my first time using file handlers if you haven't noticed lol.

Comment: @m.18 So we have established that the code seems to work, so your question is no longer about that. Instead I suppose it is about how to persist data, so that it is available if you close the program and open it again later? In that case you would call readData when launching your application and writeData just before you close it (or after every time you add/remove in case the application crashes).

Comment: Ok so it is now kind of working I was just not calling the methods. It is saving and reading but sometimes it is outputting duplicates and if an object is deleted it still remains in the file. I updated the code (Employees class) and added where I called the methods.

Comment: @m.18 This thread has gotten a little out of hand, so I recommend going through my comments and updating your question with the specific problem you're having. If others stumble upon this question, it might also make more sense then and perhaps be of help. Welcome to StackOverflow :-)

Comment: I think I managed to figure out most of it. Thanks for all your help :)

Comment: @m.18 Awesome, feel free to ask otherwise or you can accept this answer.

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code but couldn't find any problem.

why don't you try to catch Throwable and check it by debugging?

```
try { /* code */ }
catch (Throwable t) { t.printStackTrace(); }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like this
writing every object one by one using a loop

```
private static final List<Student> students = new ArrayList<>();
static File dataFile = new File("students.obf");
static File metaFile = new File("students.txt");

public static void main(String... args) throws IOException {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        Student student = new Student("id" + i, "name" + i);
        getStudents().add(student);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < getStudents().size(); i++) {
        System.out.println(getStudents().get(i).getName());
    }
    writeMetaDataFile();
    writeDataFile();
    readDataFile();

}

private static void writeMetaDataFile() throws FileNotFoundException {
    try (PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(metaFile)) {
        printWriter.print(getStudents().size());
    }
}

private static int readMetaDataFile() throws FileNotFoundException {
    try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(metaFile)) {
        return scanner.nextInt();
    }
}

private static void readDataFile() throws FileNotFoundException {
    try (FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(dataFile)) {
        try (ObjectInputStream objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(fileInputStream)) {
            for (int i = 0; i < readMetaDataFile(); i++) {
                System.out.println(objectInputStream.readObject());
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}

private static void writeDataFile() throws IOException {
    try (FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(dataFile)) {
        try (ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOutputStream)) {
            for (int i = 0; i < getStudents().size(); i++) {
                objectOutputStream.writeObject(getStudents().get(i));
                System.out.println("writing object");
            }
        }
    }
}

public static List<Student> getStudents() {
    return students;
}


static class Student implements Serializable {
    private final String name;
    private final String id;

    public Student(String id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).